# Is it possible to reference information that's currently only within a google sheet query?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-query-language, textjoin

I have a query (`=QUERY(A9:N,"Select C,D,E,F,G,H,I where B contains """&L3&"""")`) Which returns a header row and a row where the answers are either true or false - depending on the the tickboxes in the query array.

I am trying to find whichever Column has true and return the header in a `TEXTJOIN` - so that I get one cell with all the true headers if that makes sense.

My current attempt is with an array formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(" | ",true ,ArrayFormula(if(QUERY(A9:N,"Select C,D,E,F,G,H,I where B contains """&L3&"""")=true,[HELP],"")))
```

but I don't know how to return the header or rather return the value of the cell right above the true - it would be easy enough if I let it fill up a 7x2 box but again - would prefer a one-cell answer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e3FtvRGlefL154GCAYg8LpU_3jJOADZJVFBNBaOrDwQ/edit?usp=sharing
The spreadsheet is rather large but sheet in question is "Resource Node Overview"

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(" | ", 1, IF(QUERY(A9:N, 
 "select C,D,E,F,G,H,I where B contains '"&L3&"'", 0)=TRUE, C9:I9, )
```

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute nerd! thank you!!

Comment: I know but I have to wait 4 minutes - I just wanted to reply to you so you felt complimented!! - and I dont have enough rep to upvote the answer...